# pulling value from dynamic cell reference

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

[image: https://i.ibb.co/n73vHrv/gamedaydailysheet.png]

[image: https://i.ibb.co/dM8bhYy/gameday-MTD.png]

My main Base formula is to get MTD figures is

```
=SUM('1'!C8,'2'!C8,'3'!C8,'4'!C8,'5'!C8,'6'!C8,'7'!C8,'8'!C8,'9'!C8,'10'!C8,'11'!C8,'12'!C8,'13'!C8,'14'!C8,'15'!C8,'16'!C8,'17'!C8,'18'!C8,'19'!C8,'20'!C8,'21'!C8,'22'!C8,'23'!C8,'24'!C8,'25'!C8,'26'!C8,'27'!C8,'28'!C8,'29'!C8,'30'!C8,'31'!C8)
```

I need a formula that references G1 on the MTD Sheet to pull the respective value from the "dated sheet"  so if it was the 22nd MTD!G1 would be 22 and then that formula would put the value from 22 in the MTD Daily section

I have Tabs named MTD DATA 1 2 3 4 5 - 31  for each day of month EVERY Date sheet is exactly the same

At top of MTD Sheet I have in G1 the formula `=DAY(DATA!B1)` to dynamically pull the numerical date from Data sheet so every day the current date is displayed

I need to have for Daily values formula to reference Sheet 22 's  C8 cell to return JUST the DAILY calls to the MTD (Main sheet) so Id imagine the formula would look something like

```
=SUM('MTDG1'!C8)
```

Which would yield in my perfect world something like

```
=SUM('22'!C8)
```

ideally to almost like concatenate the number 22 referencing Tab 22 pulled from MTD G1 cell which is the number of the current date

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: 0]

---

try like this:

```
=INDIRECT(G1&"!C8")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: player0 you are awesome! i knew indirect was the direction but couldnt put it together .